# How to know inside jenkinsfile / script that current build is a replay?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

As in subject - is there any way to verify if current build is effect of using 'Replay' button?

Comment: Looking for the same answer... Maybe through the initial description? @freakman have you found anything?

Comment: I haven't found any flag/variable. In our solution job was ran automatically when some change was pushed to git  - so 'currentBuild.changeSets'  was not empty. Notice that when you use 'replay' currentBuild.changeSets' is not filled. It may be indication for you that job was replayed.

Comment: that's exactly the same I have observed! Thank you! Let me try that!

Comment: I'm taking it back... I constantly see it being filled with the changes... :( Still looking for an answer :(

Comment: wow, you are lucky - I was hoping to have those changes even when it's replay :D. Maybe there is some difference when other version / plugins are used. Thank you for getting back with solution below.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it as a step condition!!! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the following solution using the `rawBuild` instance from `currentBuild`. Since we can't get the class of the causes, we just verify its string value.

```
def replayClassName = "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause​"
def isReplay = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().any{ cause -> cause.toString().contains(replayClassName) }
```

This solution works for Jenkins with Blue-Ocean. References to how to get to this answer is [Jenkins declarative pipeline: find out triggering job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908390/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-find-out-triggering-job/46940063#46940063)

## Update

Using this a step condition works like a charm!

You can define a shared library like `jenkins.groovy`

```
def isBuildAReplay() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555910/how-to-know-inside-jenkinsfile-script-that-current-build-is-an-replay/52302879#52302879
  def replyClassName = "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause"
  currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().any{ cause -> cause.toString().contains(replyClassName) }
}
```

You can reuse it in a Jenkins pipeline

```
stage('Conditional Stage') {
  when {
    expression { jenkins.isBuildAReplay() }
  }
  steps {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I would avoid casting the cause to a string though, you can just do: `cause instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause`

Comment: To avoid a script approval using rawBuild and getCauses, in "Pipeline: Supporting APIs" >2.22, you can use the following function that returns a list of JSON objects,  `currentBuild.getBuildCauses("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Groovy script

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(WorkflowJob.class).each { job ->
    println("Job: ${job.name}")

    job.builds.each { build ->
        boolean isReplay = build.getCauses().any { cause -> cause instanceof ReplayCause }

        if (isReplay) {
            println("  Detected Replay: Job '${job.name}' with build number: ${build.number}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**