# Is there a Jenkins env var for Replay?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, replay

Does Jenkins provide a variable when replay is ran? If so what is that? I see in the log that is writes `Replayed` but I am not looking to scrape the console output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'cause' of which has triggered the job, in rawBuild.

```
def replayClassName = "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause​"
def isReplay = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().any{ cause -> cause.toString().contains(replayClassName) }
```

*refered from
[How to know inside jenkinsfile / script that current build is a replay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555910/how-to-know-inside-jenkinsfile-script-that-current-build-is-a-replay)